# Chrome's Getting Started example not running.

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to build a Chrome Extension to run some JSON posts but I'm having trouble even getting started.

When I use the example at http://developer.chrome.com/trunk/extensions/getstarted.html I get a popup but no pictures.

I've run Charles http://www.charlesproxy.com/ and I've determined that no request are being made.

What's going on here? Is this tutorial out dated? Can anyone explain what I need to do to get this example running or point me in the direction of a working Getting Started Tutorial?

Overall what I'm really looking to do is Post JSON to an API and then display the response in a popup. If anyone has a very rudimentary example of this that would be great too.

Answer (score 2):

There's a bug in popup.js. The script the tutorial provides right now uses `this.kittensOnFlickr_` instead of `this.searchOnFlickr_` in the `requestKittens` function.

Replace `requestKittens` with the following:

```
requestKittens: function() {
  var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  req.open("GET", this.searchOnFlickr_, true);
  req.onload = this.showPhotos_.bind(this);
  req.send(null);
}
```

and you should be good to go.

Comment: Nice! That did the trick. The Google Chrome Dev team should really think about updating their "Getting Started" tutorial.